# Data is not getting stored in mySQL database using XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have created a database in mysql using XAMPP named test226333  I am trying to send data to the table like this
"http://localhost/write_data.php?value=100"
[for database and table details screenshot click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTXpb.jpg)

My php code is

```
<?php

$dbusername = "ganesh"; 
$dbpassword = "varma";  
$server = "localhost"; 

$dbconnect = mysql_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$dbselect = mysql_select_db("test226333",$dbconnect);



$sql = "INSERT INTO test226333.data VALUES ('".$_GET["value"]."')";    


mysql_query($sql);


?>
```

Nothing is showing while entering into the link and also data is not getting stored in the database

please help me in this
Thanks in advance..

Comment: How we suppose to access localhost? :/

Comment: Please use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: Please go read up on what the most basic error control and debugging measures are when communicating with a database. This has been explained countless times already.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "ganesh";
    $password = "varma";
    $dbname = "test226333";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    /* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO <your table name>(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))) {
         echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    /* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */

    if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $val1)) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
 if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $val2)) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $val3)) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    /* explicit close recommended */
    $stmt->close();
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Switching this to `mysqli` isn't a bad idea, but just slamming `$_GET` data in the query is extremely bad. Do try and be careful when giving advice. Code like this has a way of being copy-pasted into production environments and causing serious trouble.